# copy std::vector using assignment operator

Tags: c++, stl

```
std::vector<MyStruct*> v1;
std::vector<void*> v2;
```

I have stl vector of pointer of structure.

I want to copy `std::vector<MyStruct*>` to `std::vector<void*>`.

If I use `v2 = v1`, I am getting below error:

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of
             type 'std::vector<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion).
```

How to resove this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: The problem is `v1 = v2;` would work if both are instances of the same `std::vector<T>` (and `T` provides an assignment operator) but you left out the `T` in your question.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Actually, the OP left essential details out.</s>

However, I dare to write an answer as it's actually quite clear.

Copy assignment of `std::vector` is possible when

- source and destination vector have equal element type
- element type provides copy assignment.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct T {
  int value;
};

struct U {
  int value;
  U& operator=(const U&) = delete;
};

int main ()
{
#if 1 // OK:
  { std::vector<T> v1(10), v2;
    v2 = v1;
    std::cout << "After v2 = v1; v2 has size " << v2.size() << '\n';
  }
#else // Wrong: (U has no assignment!)
  { std::vector<U> v1(10), v2;
    v2 = v1;
    std::cout << "After v2 = v1; v2 has size " << v2.size() << '\n';
  }
#endif // 1
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
After v2 = v1; v2 has size 10
```

<kbd>[**Live demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5f6fdedba17f742)</kbd>

`struct T` has (default) copy assigment but in `struct U` I have explicitly deleted it.

Changing `#if 1` to `#if 0`, the code doesn't compile anymore.

---

After OP provided the missing info, an update of my answer:

`std::vector::assign()` is an alternative when

- element type of source vector may be assigned to element type of destination vector.

This is true for assigning `MyStruct*` to `void*` in the specific case of OP.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct T {
  int value;
};

struct U {
  int value;
  U& operator=(const T &t) { value = t.value; return *this; }
};

int main ()
{
  { std::vector<T> v1(10);
    std::vector<U> v2;
    v2.assign(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1));
    std::cout << "After v2.assign(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1)) v2 has size " << v2.size() << '\n';
  }
#if 1 // OK:
  { T t[] = { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } };
    std::vector<T*> v1{ t + 0, t + 1, t + 2 };
    std::vector<void*> v2;
    v2.assign(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1));
    std::cout << "After v2.assign(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1)) v2 has size " << v2.size() << '\n';
  }
#else // Wrong: (Assignment from void* to T* not permitted!)
  { std::vector<void*> v1(10, nullptr);
    std::vector<T*> v2;
    v2.assign(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1));
    std::cout << "After v2.assign(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1)) v2 has size " << v2.size() << '\n';
  }
#endif // 1
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
After v2.assign(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1)) v2 has size 10
After v2.assign(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1)) v2 has size 3
```

<kbd>[**Live demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b989e640cfcebefa)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly trying to copy vectors containing elements of different types.  Even if the types of the *elements* in the vectors are convertible by the compiler (e.g. `double` and `int`), collections of them are not.  You can manage it using the `std::copy` function, however:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
// ...
std::vector v1<int>;
// ...
std::vector v2<double>;
std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2));
```

You mentioned that in your case, one of your vectors contains pointers.  If the pointer types are convertible by the compiler, say, copying derived-class pointers to base-class pointers, `std::copy` will work as above.

If the pointers are not convertible, then you must use `std::transform` instead of `std::copy`, and supply the appropriate cast.  For example, copying base-class to derived-class pointers:

```
class Y : public class X { ... };
std::vector v3<X*>;
// ...
std::vector v4<Y*>;
std::transform(v3.begin(), v3.end(), std::back_inserter(v4),
               [](X* arg) { return dynamic_cast<Y*>(arg); });
```